# C++ Initializing Member Variables that are Containers of Object Pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, constructor, member-variables

I apologize to ask this as I'm sure it's been answered elsewhere. I am trying to initialize a container of object pointers within the constructor of my class. The container is an array template, the class for the constructor is A and the object type is class P.

```
A.cpp:
    #include 'Array.h'
    #include 'P.h'

    
    A::A(){
    Array<P*> ps = ?

P.cpp:
   P::P(string n){
      this->name = n;
   }


Array.h:

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Array {

    public:
        Array();
                
        ~Array();
        void add(int);
        int get(int index);
        int getSize();
        bool isFull();
        int& operator[] (int);
    
    private:
        int size;
        int* elements;
        static int MAX_ARR = 256;
    
};
template <typename T>
Array<T>::Array(){
    elements = new int[MAX_ARR];
    size = 0;
}
template <typename T>
Array<T>::~Array(){
    delete [] elements;
}
template <typename T>
void Array<T>::add(int t){
    if (size >= MAX_ARR)   return;
    elements[size++] = t;
}
template <typename T>
int Array<T>::getSize(){
    return size;
}
template <typename T>
bool Array<T>::isFull(){
    return size >= MAX_ARR;
}
template <typename T>
int& Array<T>::operator[](int index){
    if (index < 0 || index >= size) {
        cerr<<"Array index out of bounds"<<endl;
        exit(0);Array
    }
    return elements[index];
}
```

wondering what should go in the question mark/ how to properly initialize said member variable. Class P is simple, has a single string as a parameter for it's constructor.

Comment: This question's shown code fails to meet Stackoverflow's requirements for showing a [mre]. Because of that it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You need to [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part, this includes any ancillary information, like any input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: With the current design `Array<P*> ps = ?` should be deleted. `ps` probably should be a class member variable in the `A` class. Although you most likely want to pick a better name. Inside the A constructor you may want to call ps.add() but it is unclear where you expect to get data to add.

Answer (score 0):

Note: By the nature of your question, I'm assuming you're not too familiar with some of the initialization syntax of C++. Apologies if this is not the case and I'm misunderstanding your question.

If you only want your `ps` variable to be initialized, then you can simply call the default constructor using that syntax:

```
A::A()
{
    // This will call the Array default constructor. There is no need for "= <something>"
    Array<P*> ps;
}
```

After that declaration the `ps` array is already initialized and you can add elements to it right away. (However if you say that its a member variable, then you don't even need that line, the `ps` default constructor will be called before you enter the `A` constructor body.)
This can be a bit counter intuitive if you come from a Java or C# background, as in those language the variable would be uninitialized with that syntax.
However in C++ you have control over if the variables are initialized on the heap or on the stack.

Heap initialization: `Array<P*>* ps = new Array<P*>();`

Stack initialization: `Array<P*> ps(); //you can also remove the () and the default constructor will be implicitly called`

More familiar stack initialization: `Array<P*> ps = Array<P*>()`
That one can be bit inefficient as a temporary Array is first created and then it is moved/copied to the `ps` variable. This is technically slower, but modern compilers can often optimize away that additional step and simply construct the Array in-place. *Edit: In your case that syntax is not available because you defined a custom destructor in your Array class, [no copy and move assignment operators will be auto-generated](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). You would need to manually implement them first.*

If you were wondering instead how to construct the array directly with its content, then I suggest you have a look at [std::initializer_list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list). By adding a constructor supporting an initializer_list to your Array class, you would then be able to use the following syntax.

```
A::A()
    // Assuming your string object can be constructed in such way.
    : ps({new P(string("foo")), new P(string("bar"))})
{}
```